# how to start a cocos2d scene from a running (uiviewcontroller) app

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, scene

since I did games with the entire cocos2d till now and I'm working for the first time on a project with a UIViewController which is responsible to start the game scenes, I'm wondering how should I do, since the appDelegate is starting with a normal UIViewController, how could I set a method on a button to start the game (e.g the fist scene of the game) ? I've been searching for example or discussion about this but I didn't found anything, every example I saw was starting the game scene from the appDelegate at the first call.

Comment: did you try to set the controller's view with the openglview created at startup ?

Comment: you mean instead of setting the navController with the root director, and call the director with setview:glview I could do the same with my custom view controller?

Comment: Never tried it but you could give it a shot.

Comment: You can start project by installing cocos2d framework into Xcode and choose project with cocos2d. No need to add extra code. Cocos2d framework will add all code.

Answer (score 0):

Just import your cocos2d layer.h and layer.m files
and to call from view controller use the following code:-

```
if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
        [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];


    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[self.view bounds]
    pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565 depthFormat:0];

    [director setOpenGLView:glView];


    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];


    [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    [director setDisplayFPS:YES];

    [self setView:glView];

    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [HelloWorldLayer scene]];
```